# Executing large sql file against a database using powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I'm trying to execute a QC script against a database. This script contains usage of cursors, a lot of sql statements (~400 lines), uses table variables and all kinds of fun stuff.

The script executes fine in SSMS.

I'm trying this to run it via powershell:

```
$adOpenStatic = 3
$adLockOptimistic = 3
$TargetDatabaseName = 'databaseCatalogName'
$DatabaseName = 'DatabaseName'
$QCChecksLocation = 'C:\thisPathWorks\QC Checks.sql'
Start-Process odbcconf -wait -ArgumentList "/A {CONFIGSYSDSN ""SQL Server Native Client 11.0"" ""DSN=$TargetDatabaseName|Server=$DatabaseName|Database=$TargetDatabaseName|Trusted_Connection=Yes""}"


$TargetConn = New-Object -comObject ADODB.Connection
$QCResults = New-Object -comobject ADODB.Recordset
$TargetConn.ConnectionString = "DSN=$TargetDatabaseName"

$TargetConn.Open()

$SQL = get-content $QCChecksLocation
$QCResults.Open($SQL,$TargetConn,$adOpenStatic,$adLockOptimistic)
```

This results in the error: Exception calling "Open" with "4" argument(s): "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another."

Any help?

Comment: If I had to take a stab at it I would imagine it is because you are passing an array from `$sql`. Does changing this line help? `$SQL = get-content -Raw $QCChecksLocation`

Comment: YUP! That did it. Thank you, Matt! If you wanna post that as an answer, I'll mark it solved (sorry, not sure how the gamification works to your advantage here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at what I hope is the correct [reference for ADODB.Recordset Open Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx) I had a suspicion that it didn't like arrays.

> *Source*
>
> Optional. A **Variant** that evaluates to a valid Command object, **an SQL statement**, a table name, a stored procedure call, a URL, or the name of a file or Stream object containing a persistently stored Recordset.

It says variant but I am sure that it does not want arrays. `Get-Content` will return a string array for a multiline file. Clean written SQL statements use more than one line so it wasn't a stretch to expect your was.

If you have at least PowerShell v3.0 then you can use the `-Raw` switch of `Get-Content` to return the file as a single string. With v2.0 you can just pipe into `Out-String`

```
$SQL = Get-Content -Raw $QCChecksLocation
$SQL = Get-Content $QCChecksLocation | Out-String
```

Both of the above commands should result with the same `$SQL`. That should work in your Open method now.